# CreatePivotTable() error - Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

**OBJECTIVE**

Create pivot table based on a dynamic range of information.

**APPROACH**

1. Identify and Activate sheet (`ws`) that contains source data (`srcData`, `lastRow`) for pivot table
2. Identify `target` sheet where new pivot table (`pvt`) will be displayed
3. Highlight and record source data (`srcData`)
4. Create pivot cache (`pvtCache`)
5. Place pivot table (`startPvt`) on worksheet & cell

**CODE**

```
Sub createPivot()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As pivotCache
Dim pvt As pivotTable
Dim srcData As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim startPvt As String
Dim target As Worksheet

'Select pivot table data
Worksheets("CONSOLIDATED").Activate
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
srcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A1:H" & lastRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Set pivot table location
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PIVOT")
startPvt = target.Name & "!" & target.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create pivot cache
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=srcData)

Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=startPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable1")

End Sub
```

*inspired by: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables*

**ISSUES**

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

@ line:

```
Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=startPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable1")
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Am I going crazy? I've proofread this code multiple times and cannot understand where I am going wrong. At this point, I am at a loss. Any help is appreciated with an explanation on why the error has occurred.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. I took your exact code and a PivotTable was generated. Are you sure that line is the problem? Is this part of a larger body of code?

Comment: @Parfait - this is the entirety of the module code. I wonder if this requires me to adjust settings within excel's vba editor?

Comment: No adjustment needed as all these objects, *pvtCache, pvtTable* are of the Excel object library. I see *ThisWorkbook* and *ActiveWorkbook* assignments. Are you working across multiple workbooks?

Comment: @Parfait I am working within the same workbook, but across different sheets. Restarting excel has resulted in dropping the original error, but the pivot table still isn't being created

Comment: @Parfait - I changed my Excel options to read R1C1 headings and restarted excel. This has solved the issue. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Interesting. I do not have such R1C1 headings set in options and still code worked for me. What is your OS? Office version? Also, consider answering your own question for future readers.

Comment: @Parfait I have Excel 2013. I will update to have my own answer, but I am not sure if changing my settings was the "solution". The sub module seems to run indefinitely which mean I can only run it once - If I have to rerun the Sub then I have to close and reopen the excel sheet.

Comment: Look into [repairing your Office installation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

@Parfait was correct, the code has no bugs. However, the macro still showed signs of freezing during the caching phase. In order to fix this error, I added the following code to the beginning of the code base.

```
'Delete previous pivottable
Worksheets("PIVOT").PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange2.Clear
```

This code removes any pre-existing pivot table in preparation for a new table.